# inverse xpath not working

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Input XML:

```
<Payheads>
    <Allowance>
        <Payhead>
            <type>fixed</type>
            <code>123</code>
            <name_en>Chairman Allowance</name_en>
            <amount>3000</amount>
            <source>SalaryProfile/Allowances/Payhead/CHA/amount</source>
        </Payhead>
    </Allowance>
    <Deduction>
        <Payhead>
            <type>Fixed</type>
            <code>234</code>
            <name_en>PF Subscription</name_en>
            <source>SalaryProfile/Deductions/Payhead/amount</source>
        </Payhead>
    </Deduction>
 </Payheads>
```

I want it to be like this:

```
<Payheads>
    <Allowance>
        <Payhead>
            <code>123</code>
        </Payhead>
    </Allowance>
    <Deduction>
        <Payhead>
            <code>234</code>
        </Payhead>
    </Deduction>
 </Payheads>
```

So I wrote an xpath expression:

```
SELECT DELETEXML(SALARY_PROFILE, '//Payhead/*[not(code)]') INTO RESULT_XML FROM DUAL;
```

But it deletes everything under `Payhead` tag. If I remove `*` before `not` function then it raises error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*[not(code)]` is a shorthand for

```
*[not(child::code)]
```

What you need is the `self` axis that has no abbreviation:

```
*[not(self::code)]
```

Comment: what if i want to keep *code* and *amount* ? because `*[not(self::code and self::name_en)]` is not working..

Comment: nvm got the ans..it should be `'//Payhead/*[not(self::code)][not(self::name_en)][not(self::amount)]'` and thanks for your help..